# Why does PFC often use OTA to do the compensation?

Tags: operational-amplifier, switch-mode-power-supply, power-factor-correction, ota

I see some design documents about PFC, they often use OTA to compensate for the circuit.
I know the OPA is voltage control voltage and OTA is voltage control current,
but I don't know why I can't use OPA to compensate for the PFC.

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Silicon designers like OTAs because they occupy a much smaller die area than their op-amp cousins. Also, for a PFC, there is no bandwidth issues as crossover is a few hertz only and no specific performance is needed.

One thing that is often overlooked though, is that with OTA, there is no virtual ground as with an op-amp. Therefore, with an OTA, you can detect an over-voltage issue by monitoring the FB pin while it is more complicated with an op-amp:

[image]

In the left side of the picture, the voltage at the FB pin is the HV bus scaled by the resistive divider. With a second voltage reference, usually 5% above the one hooked to the FB pin, you can easily detect an over-voltage condition if the divider drifts away.

If you go with an op-amp, it is more complicated as the virtual ground maintains the pin at 2.5 V as in the L6561. This is until the op-amp rails down that you can actually detect the runaway on the FB pin but it might be too late. ST had a specific IP at that time (I'm talking about the MC33262/L6561 times, before 2000) to detect a O-V condition by monitoring the current in the feedback capacitor. However, it was more complicated than with an OTA, for sure.

Then, the second minor difference is with the compensator gain: with an OTA, the resistive division ratio and the transconductance \$g_m\$ enter the picture while only the upper resistance \$R_1\$ matters for the compensator design with an op-amp.

Comment: +1, great answer as always.  One additional downside of the gm amp is that like you said the loop gain depends on gm, which can vary quite a bit, sometimes +/- 20% or more, and the min/max often isn't specified.  So you might have to be conservative with your gain margin to take that into account.

Comment: Merci *John D* for the upvote and the kind comment. Yes, \$g_m\$ is not tested in production and varies from lot to lot. Fortunately, PFC are rather friendly beasts to stabilize and I have rarely run into problems beside the interaction with the front-end filter.

Comment: If OTA is easier to use compared with OPA, why do we need to use OPA?
Any concern with using OTA to do the compensation?
How to actually detect the current of feedback capacitor?

Comment: An OTA is not easier to use than an op-amp but it occupies less silicon area (smaller dies size hence lower cost). Actually, for a type 3 compensator, an op-amp is better suited than an OTA. Regarding the OVP detection, please check the L6561 data-sheet, there is a section where the author describes the protection scheme involving current measurement in the capacitor.

Answer (score 3):

There's no reason that an op-amp compensator wouldn't work.  The gm amplifier typically saves a pin on the IC package, and in some cases (not necessarily PFC) allows for external circuitry to override the comp voltage for an external precise current limit for example.